# Running in spark MLlib in Databricks , how to interpret the one more weighs in logistic regression

Tags: python, apache-spark-mllib, logistic-regression, databricks

I have 12 feature variables, but why are there 13 weighs shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhibS.png) for logistic regression in spark MLlib Databricks? How can I interpret it?

Following [this link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.classi%20fication.LogisticRegressionModel) it says:

> "`intercept` – Intercept computed for this model. (Only used in Binary Logistic Regression, the intercepts will not bea single value, so the intercepts will be part of the weights.) ".

Is the first weighs I got is reserved for `intercept`?

[Here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/binary-classification-mllib-pipelines.html) is the code I referred to.